# Reusing salt state snippets

Tags: salt-stack

In my salt state files I have several occurrences of a pattern which consists of defining a remote repository and importing a gpg key file definition, e.g.

```
import_packman_gpg_key:
    cmd.run:
        - name: rpm --import http://packman.inode.at/gpg-pubkey-1abd1afb.asc
        - unless: rpm -q gpg-pubkey-1abd1afb-54176598

packman-essentials:
    pkgrepo.managed:
        - baseurl: http://ftp.gwdg.de/pub/linux/misc/packman/suse/openSUSE_Tumbleweed/Essentials/
        - humanname: Packman (Essentials)
        - refresh: 1
    require:
        - cmd: import_packman_gpg_keygpg-pubkey-1abd1afb-54176598
```

I would like to abstract these away as a different state, e.g.

```
packman-essentials:
    repo_with_key.managed:
        - gpg_key_id: 1abd1afb-54176598
        - gpg_key_src: http://packman.inode.at/gpg-pubkey-1abd1afb.asc
        - repo_url: http://ftp.gwdg.de/pub/linux/misc/packman/suse/openSUSE_Tumbleweed/Essentials/
        - repo_name: Packman (Essentials)
```

which will in turn expand to the initial declarations above. I've looked into custom salt states ( see https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/writing.html#example-state-module ) but I only found references on how to create one using Python. I'm looking for one which is based only on state definitions, as writing code for my specific problem looks overkill.

How can I create a custom state which reuses the template I've been using to manage package repositories?

Answer (score 1):

This is what [macros are for](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/jinja/index.html#macros)

Here is an example of simple macros for [some heavily used by me constructs](https://github.com/kiemlicz/envoy/blob/master/salt/dev/_macros/dev_tool.macros.jinja)

However in your example, why do you `cmd.run` to import key?
`pkgrepo.managed` seems to support `gpgkey` option to download the key

Comment: That's a good idea, thanks. The `pkgrepo.managed` does not seem to import the key for me. Maybe it's the zypper backed, I will investigate some more